# I have add uber ride requset button in my ios app but location is not passing to uber app

Tags: iphone, swift, uber-api

I have implement UBER ride request button in my iPhone app. When I click on the button it takes me UBER app. but can not set the drop off location that I pass from my app.

Anyone have the demo link for it?

Comment: Can you add your OpenURL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take look at the UBER documentation URL should be something like this:

```
uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=pickup_location&dropoff=drop_location&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
```

I will suggest you use coordinates:

```
uber://?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&pickup[nickname]=UberHQ&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818
```

For more just have a look at the [Uber Documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction#standard-deep-links).

Comment: hello why do we need to set this coordinates i think button will pass it when we press it from our app. or do we need to set it manually??

Comment: @KIApple you have to send it manually. if you don't assign drop-off coordinates  destination will be empty...

Comment: @O-mker : thanx for help. i can see the drop-off coordinates when send it via url. i have one more thing to ask then what is use of uber button we can pass link on click any simple button.

Comment: @KIApple You cam use a simple button with the image so you can customize in the feature. if you found my answer useful don't forget to upvote and accept it...

Comment: @O-mker: thanx :)

Comment: if i use simple button how to fetch ride information like estimated time of arrival and price estimation can you help me in this?

Comment: for price and estimate time of arrival i have to use  button.loadRideInformation() this method right?? if so button of RideRequestButton class not UIButton. so how to link of drop-off coordinates using ride request button

Comment: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/button/ios

Comment: @KIApple No you can make api calls

Comment: @KIApple Depending on needs